# How to generate validation files using doctrine schema?

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml, symfony-forms

Has Symfony2 any script to generate a [valitation yaml file](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/validation.html) with the doctrine2 schema information? I mean: [string max lenght](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/constraints/Length.html), [not-null](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/constraints/NotNull.html), [float](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/constraints/Type.html), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently ( as of 2013-05-28 ) no bundle / implementation capable of generating annotation/yml validation mappings from your doctrine mapping information.

symfony will guess the field-type in a form based on the mapping information if you dont provide the field-type ( i.e. 'text' ) in the FormBuilder::add() method explicitly but not the validation constraints.